# Как закрасить сектора картинки приведенной ниже?

Tags: java, android

Рисую примерно так:

```
  canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, 100, paint);
  canvas.drawCircle(20, 20, 50, paint);
  canvas.drawLine(0,50,100,50, paint);
  canvas.drawLine(50,0,50,100, paint);
```

Как раскрасить сектора программно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужен floodFill: [раз](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968412/how-to-use-flood-fill-algorithm-in-android) [два](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070401/android-flood-fill-algorithm/17426163#17426163)

Comment: А попроще как нибудь? Или примерчик понятный кинуть?

Comment: Попроще - картинкой...

Comment: Заготовить варианты картинок - не вариант. Вопрос именно в том, как программно, т.к. закрашивать нужно области разные по форме и много, плюс масштабирование экрана.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз вы решили рисовать линиями (drawLine), то надо так и продолжать. Для начала у вас должна быть логика, определяющая все ваши границы, а потом уже приступать к рисованию. Я взял центр окружности и закрасил левую четверть зеленым цветом.

```
public class MyView extends View {
    Paint paint;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }
    private void init(){ // значения по умолчанию
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(100,100,200,100, paint); // startX, startY, stopX, stopY линии диаметра
        canvas.drawLine(150,50,150,150, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(143,98,143,52, initGreen()); //закраска зеленым
        canvas.drawLine(135,98,135,55, initGreen()); //двигаем закраску по оси Х
        canvas.drawLine(127,98,127,58, initGreen()); //двигаем закраску по оси Х
        canvas.drawLine(120,98,120,61, initGreen()); //двигаем закраску по оси Х
        canvas.drawLine(113,98,113,61, initGreen()); //двигаем закраску по оси Х
        canvas.drawLine(105,98,105,63, initGreen()); //двигаем закраску по оси Х
        canvas.drawCircle(150, 100, 50, initBlue());
    }
    private Paint initGreen(){
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        return paint;
    }
    private Paint initBlue(){
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        return paint;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Буду пробовать делать так. Другого варианта я не нашел.